# customize SB Admin 2 Theme

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

Not a frontend developer just trying to use the template in my Django project.
I tried customizing the CSS of [SB Admin 2 Theme](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/) using sass but I'm having trouble locating the right elements to edit. I went into the CSS ([Github](https://github.com/Yankzy/SalonApp/blob/master/sb-admin-2.min.css)) it's all messy I have no idea how to deal with it. I put it through the sass compiler but no luck there. I will really appreciate it if someone can help.

All I want to do is:
Make the sidebar fixed in collapsed state and un-toggleable.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to be a bit more clear, you want it to be always toggled out on mobile view, when it's supposed to be collapsed?

Comment: Yes collapsed in mobile or desktop. No toggle out just collapsed, also even remove the toggle

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding your first issue

> Make the sidebar fixed in collapsed state and un-toggleable.

The following should do the trick:

```
body{
margin-left: 6.5rem;
}
.sidebar,.sidebar.toggled {
width: 6.5rem;
overflow: visible;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
height: 100vh;
max-height: 100vh;
z-index: 9999;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: hidden!important;
visibility: hidden!important;
-ms-overflow-style: none!important; /* IE and Edge */
scrollbar-width: none!important; /* Firefox */
}
#sidebarToggleTop {
display: none!important;
visibility: hidden!important;
pointer-events: none!important;
}
```

This goes at the end of your `style.css` file. Tell me if that's working for you.

### Regarding your second issue

> Blockquote Make the box with area graph flex width so I can replace the graph with a table tag.

I'm not quite sure I understand, could you go in more details.

Comment: The code is not working, I put it at the top as shown in the screenshot, let me know if that's not the right place. For the second one, also add a screenshot for you, it's fix width I need it to expand with content.

Comment: Place it at the bottom, it's is working on the live preview of the theme, no reason it's not working for you

Comment: Top, bottom, top and bottom. nothing works for me. I do appreciate your responses

Comment: I can see that you're adding this to the `bootstrap.css` file, this should be added under the theme `style.css` file, at the end.

Comment: it's actually sb-admin-2.min.css, this is the style file for the page, I know (or I think I know) because if I comment it out everything breaks. The problem is after pasting your snippet and it didn't do anything I tried breaking it by editing the file itself and still nothing happens. It's very strange for me. Comment the style out, or replace it with MAIN.CSS I made with SASS it breaks but edit it from within nothing change. Just lost here. Definitely missing something!